# Elastic collision in 2 dimension: Simulation

Tags: collision, ideal-gas, molecular-dynamics, simulations

I am writing an MD simulation of an ideal gas. To solve for the final velocities of two particles that collide, I came across the following code on the Internet:

```
// they are just touching.  find vector
// separating their centers and normalize it.
//m and m2 are colliding at this moment. m.dx represents velocity of molecule m in x direction. Similarly for m2.dx.

        sx = m.x-m2.x;
        sy = m.y-m2.y;
        double sxynorm = java.lang.Math.sqrt(sx*sx+sy*sy);
        double sxn = sx/sxynorm;
        double syn = sy/sxynorm;

        // find velocity of center of mass
        double totmass = m.mass + m2.mass;
        double comdx = (m.mass*m.dx+m2.mass*m2.dx)/totmass;
        double comdy = (m.mass*m.dy+m2.mass*m2.dy)/totmass;

        double pn = (m.dx-comdx)*sxn + (m.dy-comdy)*syn;
        double px = 2*sxn*pn;
        double py = 2*syn*pn;

        // subtracting this vector from m's momentum
        m.dx -= px;
        m.dy -= py;

        // adjusting m2's momentum so that total momentum
        // is conserved
        double mult = m.mass/m2.mass;
        m2.dx += px*mult;
        m2.dy += py*mult;
```

I come from a computer science background, and studied a bit of collision theory in high-school that involved the center of mass frame. The above code seems to be using it but I can't decipher what exactly it is doing. Can someone help me?

Comment: I think that you should reformulate the question so that everybody here  can  understand it without being forced to decipher an unspecified programming language.

Comment: I second freecharly. Wading through the code to figure out what it's trying to do is too much of a burden. The question should be reformulated into one that focusses on the physics issues.

Comment: @freecharly It is Java, it is visible from the 7. line. More exactly, it is Java code written by probably a beginner physics student learned to program in C. :-) The question is "too broad" (help vampiric) from the view of a programmer.

Comment: @SamuelWeir Afaik the main problem is with it that even if the question would be a pretty good one, it wouldn't be ontopic anywhere on the SE. Many good questions were closed here already (and also on programming-related sites).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this kind of collision, you need to start with a diagram:

[image]

This is the situation "in the lab frame of reference" - that is, the velocities and positions in a stationary frame of reference.

Now it turns out the math is much easier in the center of mass (COM) frame of reference, because the net momentum in that frame is zero - both before, and after the collision. This also means that the velocities $v_1'$ and $v_2'$ will be pointing in opposite directions. And since you are saying you have an ideal gas (thus perfectly elastic collisions), then in the COM frame the magnitude of the velocities after the collision will be the same as before - they will just be reflected along the line perpendicular to the line connecting the two spheres:

[image]

In the final step, you convert the velocities $u_1'$ and $u_2'$ back to the lab frame (that is, you add the velocity of the center of mass back in).

To calculate the velocity of the center of mass, you just take the vector sum of the momentum, and divide by the total mass:

```
p_x = m_1*v_1x + m_2*v_2x
p_y = m_1*v_1y + m_2*v_2y
Vx = p_x/(m_1+m_2)
Vy = p_y/(M-1+m_2)
```

I recommend that you use these diagrams, and the equations given by @ja72, to derive the correct code yourself - rather than relying on someone else's code that you don't understand.

Comment: I agree. It is much better to derive your own equations and algorithm rather than use something you don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

This is the physical concept behind the elastic impact of two point masses ($m_1$ and $m_2$):

1. There is an exchange of momentum (vector) $\vec{J}$ between the masses such as the total momentum of the system being conserved.
2. The momentum vector is along the contact normal direction $\hat{n}$ (known) with an unknown magnitude $J$ such that $$\vec{J} = J\,\hat{n}$$ for point masses the contact normal is the unit vector separating the center of mass vectors $$\hat{n} = \frac{ \vec{r}_2 - \vec{r}_1}{\| \vec{r}_2 - \vec{r}_1 \|}$$
3. The impulse changes the velocity of the center of mass by $$\Delta \vec{v}_1 = +\frac{1}{m_1} \vec{J} \\ \Delta \vec{v}_2 = - \frac{1}{m_2} \vec{J}$$ which represents an equal an opposite application of $\vec{J}$ on each mass.
4. The law of collision states that the relative velocity along the contact normal flips signs during the collision. Write the above in terms of the change in relative velocity $\Delta v$ along the contact normal $$\Delta v = -2\,v$$
5. In vector form the above is $$\hat{n} \cdot (\Delta \vec{v}_1 - \Delta \vec{v}_2) =-2\, \hat{n} \cdot (\vec{v}_1-\vec{n}_2)$$ as the vector velocities are projected along the contact normal direction $\hat{n}$ (and · is the vector dot product)
6. The above is used to find the impulse magnitude $$ \hat{n} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{m_1} + \frac{1}{m_2} \right) \hat{n} J = 2 \hat{n} \cdot \left( \vec{v}_2 - \vec{v}_1 \right)$$ and since $\hat{n} \cdot \hat{n} = 1$
   $$ J = \frac{ \hat{n} \cdot \left( \vec{v}_2 - \vec{v}_1 \right)}{ \frac{1}{m_1} + \frac{1}{m_2} } $$
7. Take this impulse and apply it to change the velocities of the masses as in step 3.

Comment: Good set of equations. I took the liberty of creating some diagrams which this answer was sorely missing...

Comment: Man, I would have given you an upvote. But hell, my reputation is too less. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @PrashantPandey As long as my answer was helpful, I can live with that :-)